# SSL redirect changes client IP address read from HTTPResponse

Tags: apache, vapor, perfect

I am using Perfect Framework for my server side application running on an AWS EC2 instance. I am using the following code to get client IP address.

```
open static func someapi(request: HTTPRequest, _ response: HTTPResponse) {

    var clientIP = request.remoteAddress.host }
```

This was working fine until I installed ssl certificate on my EC2 instance and start redirecting incoming traffic to port 443.

Now this code gives me the ip of my server, i think due to the redirect, Perfect somehow think request comes from itself.

Is there any other method to get client IP address? Or do i have to try something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling for the same problem, original client ip can be found in one of the header fields called "xForwardedFor" if there is a redirect, like the following:

```
var clientIP = request.remoteAddress.host

    let forwardInfoResut = request.headers.filter { (item) -> Bool in
        item.0 == HTTPRequestHeader.Name.xForwardedFor
    }

    if let forwardInfo = forwardInfoResut.first {
        clientIP = forwardInfo.1
    }
```

Hope this helps somebody, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should ask the people you are paying for support and whom manage the infrastructure how it works before asking us?

The convention, where an http connection is terminated elsewhere than the server is to inject an x-forwarded-for [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For). If there is already such a header, the intermediate server injects the client IP address at the front of the list.

Comment: Sorry, i am the only one working on everything (aws support is no option unfortunately) and i have limited knowledge on the topic. Thanks anyway, but i will keep the question up, considering there will be more people like me in the future building up backend applications from scratch.